# Как избежать показа DialogFragment дважды

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пример кода отображения DialogFragment(просто показывает прогресс бар)

```
public void showProgressDialog(boolean isShow) {
    if(isShow){
        if(!mProgressDialog.isAdded()) {
            mProgressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProgressDialog.TAG);
        }
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

В приложении может возникнуть ситуация, когда эта функция вызовется два раза одновременно. Для теста можно просто сделать так

```
public void showProgressDialog(boolean isShow) {
    if(isShow){
        if(!mProgressDialog.isAdded()) {
            mProgressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProgressDialog.TAG);
        }
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if(isShow){
        if(!mProgressDialog.isAdded()) {
            mProgressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProgressDialog.TAG);
        }
    } else {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Такой код крашнется с

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ProgressDialog{fffc31f #2 ProgressDialog}
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1892)...
```

Как я понял, добавление фрагмента происходит асинхронно, и поэтому isAdded() возвращает false.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли этого избежать без ввода дополнительных флагов/переменных?

Comment: А если попробовать поискать фрагмент по тегу?

Comment: @post_zeew пробовал, возвращается null

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `executePendingTransactions` после `show`.

Comment: Вылетает IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Answer (score 1):

Такая-же проблема была. Решил проблему как советовал @post_zeew.

Старый код:

```
private void showDialogCreateOrEditPhoto(Bundle args, String tag){
    PhotoDialogFragment photoDialog = PhotoDialogFragment.newInstance(this);
    photoDialog.setArguments(args);
    photoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), tag);
}
```

Новый код:

```
private void showDialogCreateOrEditPhoto(Bundle args, String tag){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) {
        //Если еще нет такого диалога, то создаем, иначе ничего
        PhotoDialogFragment photoDialog = PhotoDialogFragment.newInstance(this);
        photoDialog.setArguments(args);
        photoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), tag);
    }
  }
```

Метод showDialogCreateOrEditPhoto срабатывал при нажатии на элемент списка.
Соответственно нажать можно было несколько раз, пока не откроется диалог.

Сейчас проверяется, если есть диалог с таким тэгом, то ничего не делает.